# Best practices when using Drawer Navigator with react navigation

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-native-navigation

I'm building an app with the typical Navigator, which contains a Welcome Screen, Login Screen, Signups, etc. When a user is authenticated, I'm then switching to a Drawer Navigation. However, I'm not entirely sure I'm implementing the Drawer Navigator correctly.

Sample rootNavigator:

```
const RootNavigator = () => {
  const app = useSelector(state => state.app);
  const isLoggedIn = app.user ? true : false;
  const showWelcome = app.showWelcome;

  if (isLoggedIn) {
    return (
      <Navigator headerMode="none">
        <Screen name="Home" component={AppDrawerNavigator} />
      </Navigator>
    );
  }

  return (
    <Navigator
      headerMode="none"
      initialRouteName={showWelcome ? 'Walkthrough' : 'Welcome'}>
      <Screen name="Walkthrough" component={WalkthroughScreen} />
      <Screen name="Welcome" component={WelcomeScreen} />
      <Screen name="Login" component={LoginScreen} />
      <Screen name="Signup" component={SignupScreen} />
      <Screen name="ForgotPassword" component={ForgotPasswordScreen} />
      <Screen name="ResetPassword" component={ResetPasswordScreen} />
    </Navigator>
  );
};
```

Then, when a user is logged in, I'm returning the following for the AppDrawerNavigator:

```
const AppDrawerNavigator = () => {
  const insets = useSafeAreaInsets();

  return (
    <SafeAreaView
      mode="padding"
      style={[
        styles.safeArea,
        { paddingTop: insets.top, paddingBottom: insets.bottom },
      ]}
      edges={['right', 'left']}>
      <Drawer.Navigator
        screenOptions={{
          drawerType: 'front',
          gestureEnabled: true,
          swipeEnabled: false,
        }}
        drawerContent={props => <HomeDrawer {...props} />}>
        {/* Screens */}
        <Drawer.Screen name="Landing" component={LandingScreen} />
        <Drawer.Screen name="Profile" component={ProfileScreen} />
      </Drawer.Navigator>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};
```

The downside that I'm noticing with this type of implementation is on any of the screens where I try to detect the current view, the route returned is "Home", which appears to be an issue of how I've implemented the drawer.

What is the best way to go about this problem; how I should render the Drawer Navigation?

Comment: i am in a similar boat as you are, new to react and building some usable components. the thing is, react has been around for years now. try using ready to use themes and libraries which provide functionality that you are looking for, already optimized like crazy. not an answer. just a suggestion that will save you time. i am currently using https://reactstrap.github.io/ which already has well built components include this.

Comment: Shouldn't  `MyDrawer` be named `AppDrawerNavigator` in your example? Aside from this I don't really understand the problem. If you retrieve `route.name` inside a screen of your `AppDrawerNavigator` it won't be `Home`, but the name of that screen. Or is it that you want the active route of the `AppDrawerNavigator` in your `RootNavigator`? Aside from this I think your structure looks fine.

Comment: So, I assumed I was doing this wrong, when in my Drawer component, I was trying to get the active screen, using the following:  const route = useRoute() or const route = navigator.getCurrentRoute(). In both cases, the active route returned is Home. I would expect it to be either Landing or Profile. Yes, it should be renamed for clarity purposes 

Comment: I'm not able to replicate this behavior. Here's a [snack](https://snack.expo.io/@bvdl/hello-react-navigation-%7C-react-navigation) where I try to replicate your overall structure. If I'm missing something as far as your navigation structure goes, then you could create a snack and link it or add some more relevant code to your question.

Comment: @BasvanderLinden Yeah, that's the problem I'm facing. All of my routes inside the drawer, when I log out route.name, is "Home". Ideally, I want to get Landing / Profile, since it's a nested navigation.

Comment: Found that this returns the correct route name: const routeName = getFocusedRouteNameFromRoute(route) ?? 'Landing"';